# looking for a http load balancer implemented in python

Tags: python, weblogic, load-balancing

I'm looking to use an internal load balancing using python.
The input should be something like this:

```
Service1:
   hosts: 
     server1: 
        port: 5000
     server2:
         port: 5001
```

And then something like

```
client = MagicPythonLoadBalancer(config['Service1'])
```

and the client implements a round robin or random logic of pulling from those clients.

If one server is down, it stops "httping" it for x minutes.

I think Java has one called `WebLogic`

The closest I've found is this https://github.com/alessandrod/txloadbalancer
and I'm not even sure what it does and it hasn't been maintained lately.

Comment: Need create a shared Class. But balancing is os level action(for checking system resource, otherwise you waste additional system resource for monitoring connections)

Comment: WebLogic is not a load balancer, but an application server. To load balance WebLogic servers, a web server (Apache HTTP, IIS, etc.) is used to front the cluster nodes routing traffic as necessary.

Comment: @dsgdfg thanks, I know it will take system resources, But I will save an extra server - configuring and maintaining.

Comment: What is type of servers ? Stream, file ? You can't talk with server but any server can talk with others. My opinion: create a loopback server app for communicate each service if all service is different type. You waste a lot source if handle incoming request. Need ready not prepare when incoming a request.